# CSS Glitchs on Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, flicker

I'm trying to debug CSS on my website but can not find the fix. There are two problems only on Chrome browser: 
1) Blur animation starts and ends with flickering.
2) Bottom scrolled movie grid is partially covered with transparent background on hover

I use jQuery to blur everything except search input

```
$(".moviesearch").focus(function() {
    $('.hero > *:not(#searchbox), .right-column, .sky, #universe, #limbo').css({
        'pointer-events': 'none',
        filter: 'blur(30px)',
        webkitFilter: 'blur(30px)',
        mozFilter: 'blur(30px)',
        oFilter: 'blur(30px)',
        msFilter: 'blur(30px)',
        WebkitTransition: 'all 0.5s ease-in-out',
        MozTransition: 'all 0.5s ease-in-out',
        MsTransition: 'all 0.5s ease-in-out',
        OTransition: 'all 0.5s ease-in-out',
        transition: 'all 0.5s ease-in-out',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
        '-moz-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
        '-o-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
        'transform': 'translateZ(0)',
        '-webkit-backface-visibility': 'hidden',
        '-moz-backface-visibility': 'hidden',
        '-ms-backface-visibility': 'hidden',
        'backface-visibility': 'hidden',
        '-webkit-perspective': '1000',
        '-moz-perspective': '1000',
        '-ms-perspective': '1000',
        'perspective': '1000'
    });
});
$(".moviesearch").blur(function() {
    $('.hero > *:not(#searchbox), .right-column, #universe, #limbo').css({
        'pointer-events': 'auto',
        filter: 'blur(0px)',
        webkitFilter: 'blur(0px)',
        mozFilter: 'blur(0px)',
        oFilter: 'blur(0px)',
        msFilter: 'blur(0px)'
    });
});
```

I tried `backface-visibility: hidden` but it is not working. For the second problem I'm not able try anything as I can't understand the problem. Also I noticed that if I start search on my website and blur animation occurs with flickering, the second problem resolves. Please tell me why is this happening and how to prevent it. Here is my [WEBSITE TO INSPECT](http://rasvuyuro.ge/) Thanks!

Comment: I see the transparent background issue, but how do I see the flickering issue?

Comment: Have you tried putting all your css in a stylesheet under a class, and then only using JavaScript/jQuery to do an addClass/removeClass? That might be more efficient than applying all the styles inline.

Comment: @JonathanChaplin focus on search input to blur background

Comment: @David784 Will it solve the two problems I stated?

Comment: will it? I don't know. It's just a suggestion. It *might*, especially with the flickering, because it's a more efficient operation. IMHO it would be worth doing even if it doesn't solve your problems, because it will result in better code. Look up just about any "css best practices" out there, and rule #1 will almost always be "avoid inline css."

Comment: @AkakiKhujadze Your JavaScript is eating up all of the CPU, which is probably the reason for flickering. Browser just can't render the picture fast enough. And I have a really decent CPU and good graphics card. You have to optimize your JavaScript (jQuery code).

Comment: @BJovke And what about movie grid issue?

Comment: Yes, I've noticed it now, it wasn't clear from your question what is actually happening. When movie grid is scrolled to the bottom then it's visible. It doesn't happen in Firefox. I can't tell you more now until I take a detailed look at it.

Comment: The flickering could be caused by the browser not knowing to pre-render the element. Try initializing your elements with the blur filter set to 0px.